# Laravel Date/Time Carbon Issue

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-5

I`m developing attendance management system.

My view is like this.

[image]
What I need is if I select the time value and press `Mark here` button current data and time value need to be stored in the database according to trainee `ID`.

Here is the view for that .

```
   <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>

           <th>Trainee ID</th>
           <th>Name with Initials</th> 
           <th>Time</th>
           <th>Mark Here!</th>

        </thead>

        <tbody>
        @foreach($items as $item)

          <tr>
             <td>
                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="trainee_id" class="form-control" value="{{ $item->trainee_id }}">
                </div>
             </td>

              <td>
                  {{ $item->name_with_initials }}
              </td>

              <td>
                    <label><input type="checkbox" name="time" id="time" value="time">&nbsp; Time</label>
              </td>

              <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="Bankdetails/{{ $item->trainee_id }}">Mark Here</a>
              </td>
          </tr>
      @endforeach 
      </tbody>

 </table>
```

I know that my Controller is perfectly alright and need to be fixed.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $queryType = $request->time;
        $carbon = new Carbon('queryType');
        attendancedetails::create($request->all());

        return view('traineeattendance.attendanceo');
    }
```

Here is the necessary data model .

```
class attendancedetails extends Model
{
    protected $table = "attendancedetails";
    protected $fillable = ['id',
    'attendance_date',
    'trainee_id',
    'name',
    'starting_time',
    'end_time',
    'site_visit_time'];
}
```

Can anyone suggest me to get fixed this.

Comment: Are you sure, your controller is right ?
Did you dumped `$request->all()` ?
I think create using `$request->all()` not a good practice.

Comment: $request->all() for save data into database.my controller is wrong for what i want.so that i need to fix that

Comment: You need to add user attendence with time ? 
Your request has trainee id only so how can you add other details you described in Model

Comment: so how can i do that? can u please suggest me.

Comment: What error get you and describe your field for store in $request->all().

Answer (score 0):

You already have the current time by default in laravel. When you save a record in migrations there is a `timestamps();` input:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        ...
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

That creates a `created_at` and `updated_at` column in your DB table! And you can use `created_at` time when that input is saved to show it elsewhere!

Comment: create at is solve this..how can i get the end time.can i get it through update time ryt?

Comment: `updated_at` time is the time when the data in that row is updated. So if that is what you need then yes, you can use that time. But still I am not sure what do you want to achieve!?

Comment: i`m developing attendance management system.when trainee is come to the office i have to mark his attendant time.as well as when he/she leaves that time also need to recorded and retrieve.earlier i created a from to fill data and then save into database.but supervisor asked me to do thing which i shown in the screenshot.just select the time checkbox then send it.according to that retrieve data.